# Next/JS how to access environment variables before next app is loaded

Tags: javascript, next.js, package.json

I have an index.js file that sets up an express server with endpoints. The problem I'm running into is that some of the imports in the index.js file is accessing environment variables using the process.env. These variables are defined in the .env file.

I think what is happening is the call to the imports is happening before the next app is created and so the environment variables are not loaded.

Here's the structure of the index.js file

```
import envConsumer from './environmentConsumer'

const nextApp = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' });
nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
   const app = express();
   //The rest sets up the express endpoints
}
```

The environmentConsumer calls the process.env on a variable that's in the .env.

Here's the scripts section of the package.json to show how the application is started. The command I'm running is the dev:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node index.js",
    },
```

The structure of the project also includes a frontend which is defined in the app directory of the project. I can run this frontend by running `next dev`. The goal is to be able to run both the frontend and the backend.

One option I was considering was to change the imports so that they call the `process.env` when invoked from the `nextApp.prepare` callback. I would prefer to not do this to limit the number of changes required.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a single start command that starts the entire application and correctly loads the environment variables.

Is there a good way to start the backend along with the frontend?

Comment: I just confirmed that the environment variables are set correctly within the nextApp.prepare callback.